# Can't rename gwt-module

Tags: gwt

I've read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml) and decided to rename my gwt-module, but got a fault. IDEA automaticaly generates test.gwt.xml when I create GWT-module project. It put:

```
<module rename-to="test">
```

inside test.gw.xml. If I remove "rename-to ..." and run app, GWT-plugin gives me an error. It seems to be nesessary in gwt.xml. It is contradictional with "Renaming Modules" part of article. Why can't I remove or rename?

Here is test.gwt.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="test2">
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <entry-point class='com.ibm.temp.client.test'/>
    <servlet path='/testService' class='com.ibm.temp.server.testServiceImpl'/>
</module>
```

And test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wrapper HTML for App</title>    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.ibm.temp.test/com.ibm.temp.test.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
<h1>Simple Application</h1>    
<div id="input-container"/>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I checked it there is no problem with that. I am using GWT SDK 2.5.1 and app-engine 1.7.4. Please give detailed error

Comment: I usually check in this case,html's  javascript-src attribute and run cinfiguration.sometime old value exists.

Comment: "Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997" I've got this in chrome! I've reinstalled several time this stupid plugin and restarted chrome, but it was still going bad. I decided to check my attempts in firefox. It was better way, but I still can't understand, how it works! I create default GWT-app in IDEA, and put Button in onLoadModule and run - in FF it's greate and all is working, but if I change "rename-to="ANOTHER_NAME" and start app, I can see only welcome text without my button on the page... Why? I am using "gwt-2.5.1" and don't use App-Engine

Comment: Create a html page in war, and use the script (if rename not specified full_packname.nocache.js will be the js ) in html and access that page,like <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.my_apps.gwt.GWTTestApp1/com.my_apps.gwt.GWTTestApp1.nocache.js"></script>

Comment: IDEA create html in war with "<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test/test.nocache.js">" by default! If I press Ctrl and go cursor to "test/test.nocache.js" and click on this IDEA goes to test.gwt.xml page, but if I rename test in "rename-to="test2"" and do all prev manupulation, IDEA can't open gwt.xml again. It means, that I can't simply rename my gwt-module, and I have no idea why = (

Comment: Is your problem solved by changing the script tag in html with full pack name of nocache.js?

Comment: unfortunately, no = (

Comment: Provide your gwt.xml and html page

Comment: Look it up in my question!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test2/test2.nocache.js"></script>

Change script tag like this

Comment: OMG, thx a lot!!!! It is now working!!!! Thank you so much, I really apreciate your help!!! If you make your advice like the answer, I can award you)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47181/discussion-between-idntknw-and-nightin-gale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change script tag like this.The problem is that ur browser cannot find the nocache.js file.
If module rename to abc , nocache.js will be in war/abc/abc.noacache.js
If module not renamed,it will be in war/full package name of gwt.xml/full package name.nocache.js

For your case it will be as,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test2/test2.nocache.js"></script>
```